# Jenkins - Get the number of builds in Queue for a given job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

is there a way to get number of builds that are in Queue for a given job ?

I need to get build numbers that are waiting in queue. Is it possible to get that?

To start with, even if I can just get number of builds in queue would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question. You can get all the Pending items in the queue with the following code.

```
def queue = Jenkins.instance.queue

queue.getItems().each { item ->   
  println "Pending item found "
     
}
```